# I don't have the "Web Application" in the "Add Frameworks Support dialog" in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2016.1

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I opened a Maven pom.xml project file that describes a project that creates a WAR file.

I want to enable Web Application support in the hope that that will help me edit JSPs.

I follow the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html) but I do not have the "Web Application" option.  I see this instead:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had to enable the plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets".  I enabled JSP Support, thinking it would enable all I needed for JSP support - clearly not.  Annoying

Comment: Hi, what's the result of enabling the plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets"? I need to add the Web application option in Add frameworks support, did this do the trick? Because I cannot add this plugin to my IDEA (Community version) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to enable the plugin "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets". I enabled JSP Support, thinking it would enable all I needed for JSP support - clearly not. Annoying